# How to get scene change events in cesium?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I'd like to detect every time the camera position, heading, pitch or roll changes on Cesium view so that I can update a display showing these values. After quite a bit of searching, I eventually discovered that I can add an event handler to the not-at-all-intuitive `preRender` or `postRender` events on the widget's Scene object. However, those events both fire continuously, hundreds of times per second. I would guess they are firing once per clock tick. Is there another event I can register for that will simply fire after the view of the map has been changed? I'm looking for something close to Leaflet's `moveend` event and `preRender` and `postRender` aren't it.

Failing that, is there any way I can get `preRender` or `postRender` to fire only when something has actually changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend one of the following solutions:

- set an interval that is polling the camera position at whatever frequency makes sense for your application.

  ```
  var intervalHandle = setInterval(function() {
    var camera = viewer.scene.camera,
      store = {  position: camera.position.clone(),
                 direction: camera.direction.clone(),
                 up: camera.up.clone(),
                 right: camera.right.clone(),
                 transform: camera.transform.clone(),
                 frustum: camera.frustum.clone()
              };
    //update UI elements
    ...
   }, 1000); // every 1 second whatever is best for your application
  ...
  ```
- Attach an event trigger on the instigator of the change.  If a mouse, then on mouseup. If keyboard, attach on keyup.

  The CameraEventAggregator object has a member called "anyButtonDown" which would be useful for mouse state changes.
- You may also be able to use the Camera's FlightCompleteCallback as well.  That should trigger whenever the camera is done moving if you used the helper methods to move it.

Answer (score 18):

Another solution that doesn't use a timer is to listen for the cameras move start and move end events.

```
viewer.camera.moveStart.addEventListener(function() { 
     // the camera started to move
});
viewer.camera.moveEnd.addEventListener(function() { 
     // the camera stopped moving
});
```

These sound more like the events you are looking for.

[Edit] :
While the inertia spin and zoom are enabled by default and look kinda cool, they can be disabled very easily. This will make it so the moveEnd event is fired as expected. Here is how you can disable the inertia.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer();

viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.inertiaSpin = 0;
viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.inertiaTranslate = 0;
viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.inertiaZoom = 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the user spins the globe, i.e. with inertia, it only seems to be triggered with a clean mouse down, move, mouse up...

Comment: There is an open bug on their gitHub for this issue. I currently have the same issue. https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/2839 Hope they fix that soon.

Comment: @Adam See my edit, if you don't need the inertia spin, this works very well.

Answer (score 3):

Using cesium v1.30, you can use this code:

```
viewer.camera.changed.addEventListener(function() {
  var deg = Math.round( Cesium.Math.toDegrees(viewer.camera.heading))
  console.log('Heading:', deg)

  var deg = Math.round( Cesium.Math.toDegrees(viewer.camera.pitch))
  console.log('Pitch:', deg)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044819/3092437 you probably want to set `viewer.camera.percentageChanged` to some small value close to `0` (but with `0` value `camera` tends to generate `change` events all the time). I use `0.001`, it gives pretty good events frequency at all zoom levels.

Answer (score 1):

Actual answer:

```js
viewer.scene.morphStart.addEventListener(function(ignore, previousMode, newMode) {

});
```

There's also `morphComplete`.

https://www.cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Scene.html?classFilter=scene#morphComplete